# Is it possible to use a LOAD DATA INFILE type command to UPDATE rows in the db?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Pseudo table:

```
 | primary_key | first_name | last_name | date_of_birth |
 | 1           | John Smith |           | 07/04/1982    |
```

At the moment *first_name* contains a users full name for many rows. The desired outcome is to split the data, so first_name contains "John" and last_name contains "Smith".

I have a CSV file which contains the desired format of data:

```
 | primary_key | first_name | last_name |
 | 1           | John       | Smith     |
```

Is there a way of using the LOAD DATA INFILE command to process the CSV file to UPDATE all rows in this table using the primary_key - and not replace any other data in the row during the process (i.e. date_of_birth)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. While [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/load-data.html) has a REPLACE option, it will actually **replace** the row in question  - that is, delete the existing one and insert a new one.

If you configure your LOAD DATA INFILE to only insert certain columns all others will be set to their **default** values, not to values they currently contain.

Can you modify your CSV file to contain a bunch of UPDATE statements instead? Should be reasonably straightforward via some regex replaces.

Answer (score 7):

In this situation I usually `LOAD DATA INFILE` to a temp table with identical structure. Then I do `INSERT` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` from the temp table to the real table. This allows for data type checking without wrecking your real table; it's relatively quick and it doesn't require fiddling with your .csv file.

Comment: I think also this is the most efficient solution as the REPLACE can be slow. And your solution can manage the inserts (new records) and update (existing records) at once.