# MYSQL Bulk "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." via "LOAD DATA INFILE"

Tags: mysql, load, performance

Hej,

I need to mass-update a table. Am I allowed to use mysql's "LOAD DATA INFILE" Statement together with "INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statements to fulfill my task?

Comment: Take a look at this related thread:
[mysql duplicates with load data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965001/mysql-duplicates-with-load-data-infile

Comment: that's not quite what I'm looking for, I got the statement's ready to go, so I just want to query them. In addition wouldn't be there to much time going by when "SELECT ..."-ing from the temporary table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirements, you may be able to accomplish this using the `REPLACE` option of [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). From the manual:

- If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other
  words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique
  index as an existing row. See Section 12.2.7, “REPLACE Syntax”.

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE your_table
(column1, column2, ...)
```

Comment: so how should the entries in the file look like? I guess it shouldn't be like that: `INSERT INTO myTable (coloumn1,...) (value1,...)`

Comment: The default file format is tab-delimited, but you can override the field and line terminators to import a CSV or other format. Take a look at the doc page for LOAD DATA INFILE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I issued the following query but the database wont be filled...`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "path/to/my/file/sqldump.txt" REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY ';'`

Comment: Does your text file contain every column form the table, in the exact same order they appear in the table definition?

Comment: yea, the first row gets properly inserted, the other strangely not...phpmyadmin tells me that only 1 row gets inserted too

Comment: Try specifying a line terminator, such as `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

Comment: thanks, now it seems to be completely solved...thanks for your help!