# CSV to Mysql import script to match fields

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Is there such a script out there or way of importing data from a CSV into mysql that can match the first field so instead of overwriting data will just update missing fields or values in rows? Hope I have explained myself clearly enough!

Example:

```
1,john,doe,programmer
2,jane,doe,accountant
3,judy,doe,manager
1,john,doe,cto
```

Assuming the first field is an ID, I want the script to insert when a record does not exist but update when the ID already exists, so John Doe would first get inserted as a programmer, but then updated to be a CTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en), in the [LOAD DATA section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> The REPLACE and IGNORE keywords control handling of input rows that
>   duplicate existing rows on unique key values:
>
> ```
> If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows.
> In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index
> as an existing row. See Section 12.2.7, “REPLACE Syntax”.
>
> If you specify IGNORE, input rows that duplicate an existing row
> on a unique key value are skipped. If you do not specify either
> option, the behavior depends on whether the LOCAL keyword is
> specified. Without LOCAL, an error occurs when a duplicate key value
> is found, and the rest of the text file is ignored. With LOCAL, the
> default behavior is the same as if IGNORE is specified; this is
> because the server has no way to stop transmission of the file in the
> middle of the operation.
> ```

So I believe that if you set the field where you store the names as an primary key or unique index, you should be able to do:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE yourtable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(id, name, surname, etc);
```

---

*update:*

*just found some more resources on the subject:*

[mysql duplicates with LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965001/mysql-duplicates-with-load-data-infile)

http://support.modwest.com/content/6/253/en/how-do-i-import-delimited-data-into-mysql.html

http://codeinthehole.com/archives/35-How-to-sync-a-MySQL-table-between-two-remote-databases..html

Answer (score 0):

try  the  following may be  helpful  for you[CSV TO MySQl](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Code/PHP-CSV-Importer-20/)

good luck